# Will doing this keep the mysql connection open?

Tags: c#, mysql, caching

Basically i store a certain dataset in asp.net cache. What i'm wondering is if doing it this way will keep the mysql connection open? even though i'm using the "using" statement?

```
String cacheName="MY_QUERY_QACHE";

IEnumerable<DataRow> datarows = (IEnumerable<DataRow>)HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheName];

if(datarows==null){
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("MY CONNECTION STRING")){
        conn.Open();
            String strSQL="SELECT * FROM my_table etc... etc....";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            cmd.Prepare();

            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds);

            datarows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
        conn.Close();
    }

    HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(cacheName,
        datarows,
        null,
        DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
        System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
        System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal,
        null
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't see why it would you explicitly close your connection. Your dataows is a separate object from the connection object in which looks to be properly disposed of.  What makes you think its staying open? Are there errors or messages to lead you to think that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The *Using Statement* will adhere to the following:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and
>   instantiate it in a using statement. The using statement calls the
>   Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it
>   as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope
>   as soon as Dispose is called. Within the using block, the object is
>   read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.
>
> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can
>   achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and
>   then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the
>   using statement is translated by the compiler. The code example
>   earlier expands to the following code at compile time (note the extra
>   curly braces to create the limited scope for the object)

The usage of that statement should ensure that the connection is *closed* no matter what happens.  As noted the connection will still be closed even with an *Exception*.  The reason is your connection does not exist out of this:

```
// Connection Doesn't Exists

using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
{
    // Connection Exists
}

// Connection Doesn't Exists.
```

As you can see by the above code, anything that falls out of those brackets becomes *out-of-scope* which will initiate the `IDisposable` interface with the method `Dispose` to remove the resource.  If you didn't utilize the *using* then you would leave it open and become responsible for handling it.

Hopefully that answers your question.  There is great detail on Microsoft's Developer Network on this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MySqlConnection` object doesn't exist outside the scope of the `using` block. Within a `using` block, `Dispose` is called on the object which implements `IDisposable` on exit. Objects which implement `IDisposable` will not automatically dispose if not declared in a `using` block. In this case, `Dispose` will need to be called manually to clean up resources.

Comment: The first statement doesn't imply the second.  It's possible for an object to not be in scope anywhere but for the connection to not be closed.  The connection is closed, but it's closed because the `using` statement will call `Dispose` on the connection when it leaves scope, and that method will close the connection.  If a `using` weren't used, and no `Close` or `Dispose` explicitly called, it could leave scope without closing the connection.

Comment: I have updated my answer with corrections as suggested in your comment. Thanks for pointing out that the second statement isn't implied!

Comment: Still not correct.  It's not "because the object implements `IDisposable`.  You aren't *allowed* to use a `using` if the type doesn't implement `IDisposable`, and if the type does implement `IDisposable` and you didn't have it in a `using` or call `Dispose` it wouldn't be disposed.  The point here is that the `using` itself calls `Dispose` on the object.

Answer (score 1):

The point of "using" is to invoke disposal (cleanup) when execution leaves the using scope. The connection object inherits from IDisposable so that it can do cleanup when required (and not wait for garbage collection), and for a connection, cleanup means terminating the database connection.

So, yes, outside the using scope, there will be no connection to the database.